# SQL BigQuery - How to convert date(2020-11-14 16:04:15 UTC) to WEEKDAY value (0-6)

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, weekday

I am currently working through this. Here's some relevant [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date)

I have a time date column in { 2020-11-14 16:04:15 UTC } format. I want to end up with a column with an integer 1-7 corresponding to the day of the week. 1 = Sunday and 7 = Saturday.

Currently, I have this that works for a specific date.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE '2013-12-25') AS the_day
```

How could I apply this function to a whole column?

thank you for any help.

SQL BigQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the example.

```
WITH
org_table AS (
    SELECT DATE('2013-12-25') as org_col
    UNION ALL SELECT '2013-12-26'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2013-12-28'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2013-12-29'
)
SELECT
  org_col,
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM org_col) AS the_day
FROM org_table
ORDER BY org_col
;
```

p.s.
To apply with your existing query, replace org_table.

```
WITH
org_table AS (
    SELECT `your_column` as org_col
    FROM `your_table`
)
...
```

Comment: Hello, I am not sure how I would apply this solution. For the dates after the UNION ALL SELECT would I need to enter each relevant date manually?

Comment: No, above is just an example. You can replace `org_table` subquery with your own table.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you know what the first section starting with WITH is referenced as in documentation? I'm looking to try to understand better what I did.

Comment: Do you mean this [WITH clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause) document?

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from the documentation of date functions 'Extract' example 2.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions?hl=ar-YE#extract

```
SELECT
  date,
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM date) AS the_day
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2015-12-23', '2016-01-09')) AS date
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to apply this solution and am running into some issues. I wasn't clear in my question but, the date column is not sequential so using generate_date_array won't reflect the data in the column accurately. Do you know if there is a way to use the ARRAY_AGG() function to create a new array from the date time column.  <https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions>  and <https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#arrays_and_aggregation> are links to relevant documentation.